# Cannot unpickle an instance of a class which inherits from `time`

Tags: python, time, pickle

Consider the following class, which inherits from `datetime.time`:

```
class TimeWithAddSub(time):
    _date_base = date(2000, 1, 1)

    def __new__(cls, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None):
        obj = super(TimeWithAddSub, cls).__new__(cls, hour, minute, second, microsecond, tzinfo)
        obj._as_datetime = datetime(2000, 1, 1, hour, minute, second, microsecond, tzinfo=tzinfo)
        return obj
```

Trying to unpickle it gives the following error:

```
>>> t = TimeWithAddSub(10, 11, 12)
>>> b = pickle.dumps(t)
>>>    b'\x80\x04\x95T\x00\x00\x00\x00\x....' 
>>> t2 = pickle.loads(b) 
>>>    ... in __new__ ... TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

After some digging, it seems that the `__new__()` function in the unpickled object does not get the correct parameters:

- `hour` is set to `b'\x0b\x0c\r\x00\x00\x00'`
- the rest of the parameters get their default values (`minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None`)

I've tried overriding `__reduce__()` and then `__getnewargs__()`, but both approaches result in the same error.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that `datetime.time` implements `__reduce_ex__()`, [which takes precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce_ex__) over `__reduce__()`.

Once I implemented `TimeWithAddSub.__reduce_ex__()`, overriding the implementation in the base class, the problem was resolved:

```
class TimeWithAddSub(time):
    _date_base = date(2000, 1, 1)

    def __new__(cls, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None):
        obj = super(TimeWithAddSub, cls).__new__(cls, hour, minute, second, microsecond, tzinfo)
        obj._as_datetime = datetime(2000, 1, 1, hour, minute, second, microsecond, tzinfo=tzinfo)
        return obj

    def __reduce_ex__(self, protocol):            
        return type(self), (self.hour, self.minute, self.second, self.microsecond, self.tzinfo)
```

Comment: I've written my code without reading yours - certainly, by making the reduction of h, m, s as separate integers instead of the compact bytes the original implementation generates also works. The customization of datetime.time state being pickled to a few bytes make sense in Python, since it reduces the serialized state to a few bytes - but it is not that important for a custom class.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille - done

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not inheriting from `time` - the problem is customizing `__new__` - Pickle by default will call `__new__` with the class as the sole parameter, and then try to set the instance's attributes directly in its `__dict__`. However, `datetime.time()` itself makes use of `__new__`, and therefore has a custom behavior when pickling/unpickling that we have to understand and ensure it is reproduced when unpickling.

By introspecting (using Python's `pdb.pm()` in interactive mode) into the error that takes place, unpickle is passing into the second argument to `__new__` a byte sequence with the internal state of the original `time` object - so, it does customize the pickle protocol in a way that when unpickled, it takes an special, sole, first parameter as bytes, instead of an integer each for h, m ,s and an obj for TZ.  By omitting m, s, tz when calling the original `time.__new__`  we can bypass this problem.

Fiddling a little bit more with unpickling your class in the interactive mode, I could figure out that when unpickling the tzinfo is passed as the second positional argument to `time.__new__` - so, I wrote the code accordingly.

As a final note, since this unpickling behavior of `datetime.time` is not documented, as far as I am aware of, it is not guarranteed that this will work for newer Python versions - I've tested it for Python 3.11 and 3.12:

```
class TimeWithAddSub(time):
    _date_base = date(2000, 1, 1)

    def __new__(cls, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None):
        if isinstance(hour, int):
            obj = super(TimeWithAddSub, cls).__new__(cls, hour, minute, second, microsecond, tzinfo)
        else:
            tzinfo = minute
            obj = super(TimeWithAddSub, cls).__new__(cls, hour, tzinfo)
            hour, minute, second, tzinfo = obj.hour, obj.minute, obj.second, obj.tzinfo
            
        obj._as_datetime = datetime(2000, 1, 1, hour, minute, second, microsecond, tzinfo=tzinfo)
        return obj
```